# Facebook Graph Search Api filter Likes

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api, filter

My question is very simple :

On the Facebook Graph Search Explorer v2.3, im fetching the likes by the /me/likes URL, the JSON result prompts very well by getting all the "likes" that have been liked by a user (me), and I would like to know how can I filter those likes in order to have only "Musician/Band" category for example.

Ive been looking everywhere and couldnt find what im looking for.

Thank you in advance for your help.
Youssef

Answer (score 2):

Currently, there is no way to filter the results. You will have to go through all entries on your own and implement your own filter with PHP.

But you can use some specific endpoints too, like `/me/books` or `/me/music`.

You can find all endpoints in the docs: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.5/user

Comment: Thanks for your help.You positively sure about this ? I dont need to search further about this ?

Comment: i am 100% sure about it. you can only use the existing endpoints, filtering in those is not possible right now.

Comment: this is no longer true. Please see either Youssef El Gharbaoui or my answer.

Comment: and you downvoted my answer just because it is no longer true? it was true when i answered...actually, it is still true, those are just different endpoints. they existed since years. but that´s not really filtering. i´ve added that information to my answer now.

Answer (score 1):

I have found the solution to my problem.

Luckely for me, I wanted to filter the Likes by Music/Band category.
Ive found that there is a "music" tagg that I had to use instead of the "likes" tagg.

In other words, the URL would be : **/me/music** instead of **/me/likes** and it results all the likes for the specific Music category.

Hope this helps anyone who had the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me too: `'me?fields=music'`

Some of the others that you could use instead of 'music' can be found at the [Facebook Documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user)

One can also have multiple fields like `'me?fields=music,favorite_teams'`.

Thanks to Youssef El Gharbaoui for getting me started in this direction.